# Is it possible to use Azure Analysis Services as the backend to a web app hosted on an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-analysis-services

Instead of AzureSQL --to- App Service website

AzureSql --to-> Azure Analysis Service --to--> App Service Website

The only insructions we see online is how to connect AAS to Powerbi, Excel Etc. Is it possible to use it as a backend to a website?

Answer (score 1):

You can't seamlessly connect to analysis services from azure sql. Linked server feature is not available on azure sql, instead we get https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview which doesn't really help you in this scenario.

Atm your only option is to connect to AAS, get records you want, insert it to database and do normal query.

In MS SQL server you can define analysis services as linked server and query it directly from from tsql with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql but even in this case it might be a good idea to copy result of open query to sql table first and then use that table in joins. MS SQL doesn't really know how many records will be returned by open query so in many scenarios it will produce sub optimal plans for queries that use open query results.

Comment: OK what about connecting from an Azure Website directly to Azure Analysis Services

Comment: Here is an example of how to connect to AAS from c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-programming-compatibility-level-1200/add-a-data-source-to-tabular-model-analysis-services-amo-tom